# Adding dynamic and multiple fields for user profile using profile2 module in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, users

I am creating profile like linkedin.
Where user can have multiple education fileds and he can add/modify dynamically.
Is there any plugin which suits my requirements.

The nearest I found is profile2 which is promising but does not provide me multiple entry functionality.

Can Drupal help me out how to fix this problem?

Thanks in Advance.
Yatendra

Edit : I want profile types like linkedin education wizard. i.e. if user had entered education detail one time then there should be two option first one for editing education detail and second one for adding more education detail.

Comment: you can add field to the user account at `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields` and set the number of values to multiple (as per your req.), and if need the fields as collection than give try to field collection module

Comment: Thanks Ankit!!. Yes it works for fields but I have multiple profile types (forms for profile) and I want to open same form again and again for adding newer values of same profile type.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I have to say that Ankit's comment was on the right track. Install and enable [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection), because you will use this to group each instance of your education details fields.

Depending on whether or not you use [Profile 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2), create a Field Collection-type field at `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields` or `/admin/structure/profiles/manage/<profile_type>/fields`. The number of values for the field collection field should be greater than one or unlimited. Finally, create your education details fields at `/admin/structure/field-collections/<field_collection>/fields`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with a mixture of the [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module and setting the various fields to 'Unlimited'. Here is an excerpt about it from the module's project page:

> ... allows you to manage sets of dependencies between fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the right condition.
>
> When editing a node (or any other entity type that supports fields, like users and categories), the dependent fields are dynamically modified with the [States API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7).
> You can, for example, define a custom “Article teaser" field that is shown only if a "Has teaser" checkbox is checked.